# rails 4 create records in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 4 app, I would like to have a button for adding new default records for a user.

Button in priorities/index.html.erb:

```
<%= button_to "Add Default Values", :helper => "default_priorities" %>
```

Code in helpers/priorities_helper.rb

```
module PrioritiesHelper
  def default_priorities
    Priority.create("prioritycode"=>"3 Low")
    Priority.create("prioritycode"=>"2 Medium")
    Priority.create("prioritycode"=>"1 High")
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: priority
```

Controller line getting the error:

```
  params.require(:priority).permit(:user_id, :prioritycode, :description, :prioritynumber)
```

Comment: I would strongly discourage creating those records in a helper method. This breaks the MVC architecture rules, since helpers are for views.

You should probably be creating the records in a controller. But I am not sure exactly what you models, and controllers you have. Can you give a bit more background of what these Priority records are for?

Comment: What would be a better approach?  I'm trying to allow each user to add default records for code tables.

Comment: So you have a Priority model and a User model. How do they relate?

Comment: user has_many :priorities

Comment: todos belong_to :priorities (and :user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to recommend the best solution, without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve. You definitely should avoid creating records inside a helper though (it's not MVC).

I would probably create an action on your **PrioritiesController** like this:

```
def create_default

  # Grab the user you want
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])

  # Create the priories through the association
  @user.priorities.create(prioritycode: "3 Low")
  @user.priorities.create(prioritycode: "2 Medium")
  @user.priorities.create(prioritycode: "1 High")

  redirect_to priorities_path, notice: "Defaults created!"
end
```

Define a route like in **routes.rb** like:

```
resources :priorities do
  collection do
    post :create_default
  end
end
```

Then in **priorities/index.html.erb** you could do:

```
<%= button_to "Add Default Values", create_default_priorities_path(user_id: params[:user_id]) %>
```

The above might change depending on how you are getting the user record. E.g. if you are using Devise, you might be working with **current_user** and you wouldn't need to pass the user_id through the params etc.

You also might consider moving the creation of these records out of the controller, and into the Priority model: Think skinny controllers, fat models. This might look like:

```
def self.create_defaults_for(user)
  create(prioritycode: "3 Low", user: user)
  create(prioritycode: "2 Medium", user: user)
  create(prioritycode: "1 High", user: user)
end
```

And your controller method would then look like:

```
def create_default

  # Grab the user you want
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])

  # Create the priories through the association
  Priority.create_defaults_for(@user)

  redirect_to priorities_path, notice: "Defaults created!"
end
```